# Wifi or LAN access for Android 6 on Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, android

I was able to boot my Raspberry Pi 2 with Android 6 with this image http://www.mediafire.com/download/ycwtzp6w8x66lcz/and6vc4.img.tar.bz2 (from this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnGDSgES1T0))

The performance seems fine to me, however there is no support for LAN and Wi-Fi what can be done to provide support for LAN or Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, unless you're super keen and want to get to grips with the project code. As far as I can make out, the creator's personal page is [here](http://geektillithertz.com/wordpress/index.php/2016/01/13/android-gpu-raspberry-pi-update-2/). He's posting updates regarding the project to the [Android-rpi Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-rpi/marshmallow$20vc4/android-rpi/YW_gGr8wZkk/ErK766oGCQAJ). Finally, the code is all hosted on Github [here](https://github.com/peyo-hd/local_manifests) and [here](https://github.com/peyo-hd/device_brcm_rpi2).