# can (and how do) android and pi intergrate?

Tags: pi-2, android

Is there a way to run an android platform on the *raspberry pi 2 model **b***?

How much CPU power will this new investment actually have?

Comment: Related (contains current comment too) http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56/can-i-install-android

Comment: See also: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41975/wifi-or-lan-access-for-android-6-on-pi-2

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the redundant "How can it be done?" and non-nonsensical bit about the google play store.

Answer (score -3):

It will be no problem, actually. AOSP(Android OpenSource Project) fits perfectly fine even on Pi B+, used it myself.